# SocketIo - Additional event listeners being added every time routerview page is visited

Tags: events, socket.io, vuejs3, vue-router

I have a vue3 application where I have a main layout and pages embedded within it using routerviews.

The problem I have is that everytime I go to a routerview on which I use a socketIO eventlistener, it seems that on every visit an additional eventlistener is added.

This results in the same message received being dealt with multiple times.

Below is the content of sub-page that is called within the main layout as .
What I observe is that the first time I visit it, and emit a "new_insert" event, I see 1 entry in the console.

The next time I navigate to this view, and I emit an event, I see 2 entries, and so forth.

It is as if navigating away does not kill the existing socket.on-listener, and coming to the routerview again adds an additional one.

Any ideas how to deal with this problem?

```
<script lang="ts">
import { socket } from "../services/socket";
export default {
  setup () {
    socket.on('new_insert', (inserted_id: number) => {
      console.log(inserted_id) // -> emits 1 entry the first time I go to the page, and additional ones for every subsequent visit
    })
  },
};
```

The services/socket.ts file:

```
import { io } from "socket.io-client";
export const socket = io('', {path: '/absproxy/3000/socket.io/'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to answer the question myself.

```
import { onBeforeUnmount } from 'vue' 
  setup () {
    ...

    onBeforeUnmount(() => {
      socket.off(); // This removes all event listeners for the socket
    });
  }
```